# Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

I'm on a Mac OS Catalina trying to wipe a drive via command line.

```
⚡️  Desktop  diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.8 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     843.8 GB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 80.6 MB    disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                526.6 MB   disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      4.2 GB     disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Lacie 1 TB              999.9 GB   disk2s2

⚡️  Desktop  diskutil eraseDisk ExFAT NONAME /dev/disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk                                                                                                       
[   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \ ]
```

I kept getting

```
⚡️  Desktop  diskutil eraseDisk ExFAT NONAME /dev/disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk                                                                                                       
Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk
```

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
diskutil eject disk2s2
```

Repeat that and `sudo fuser -c /dev/disk2s2` to kill or quit any processes that are blocking the eject.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the process who was using the disk was Finder, so I just restarted by holding **option + right click** and selecting relaunch

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while attempting to merge two partitioned sectors on a drive and neither suggestion worked for me. One was formatted APFS, the other MAC OS Extended. The following worked for me:

- format the APFS sector to Mac OS Extended
- merge the two sectors into a single partition